# Android broadcast receiver doesn't work: the binding failed and is unable to assign request address

Tags: android, python, sockets, udp, broadcast

For an assignment, I am trying to set up android device to receive UDP broadcast from my python program on the laptop.

The python sender will send some data over broadcast every 5 seconds and the receiver is expected to receive and display the data. However, the data is unable to be received on the android receiver.
I am currently using a Samsung S3 as my android device for testing.

One main error identified is that the binding failed and is unable to assign request address.

Below are the modified code found on the web for my purpose.

### PYTHON SENDER

```
# Send UDP broadcast packets

port = 50001

import sys, time
from socket import *

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)

while 1:

    data = repr(time.time()) + '\n'
    print data
    s.sendto(data, ('192.168.0.14', port))
    time.sleep(5)
```

---

### ANDROID RECEIVER CODE

```
class receiveUDP implements Runnable {
    final String[] text = new String[1];
    final int server_port = 50001;
    // create buffer
    final byte[] message = new byte[1500];
    final DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);


    public void run() {
        DatagramSocket s = null;
        while (true) {
            try{
                WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                WifiManager.MulticastLock lock = wifi.createMulticastLock("Main");
                lock.acquire();
                s = new DatagramSocket(server_port, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.14"));

                Log.d(MainActivity.class.getName(), "Created socket");
                s.receive(p);
                lock.release();
                text[0] = new String(message, 0, p.getLength());
                Log.d(MainActivity.class.getName(), "message:" + text[0]);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Toast.makeText(context, "Received message: "+text[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        textResponse.setText(text[0]);
                    }

                });
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                Log.e(MainActivity.class.getName(), "An unexpected error occurred", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(MainActivity.class.getName(), "An unexpected error occurred", e);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                Log.e(MainActivity.class.getName(), "An unexpected error occurred", e);
            } finally {
                if (s != null) s.close();
                Log.d(MainActivity.class.getName(), "Closing socket");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The title is misleading. This is not a Broadcast Receiver, you are trying to receive data with a Datagram Socket.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE in the application's manifest file?

Comment: Yes I did! And it still has the same problem

Comment: Did you allow the port via firewall?